# If it possible to submit form form Ajax with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, leaflet

I have an application using Flask and JavaScript. I have a function in JavaScript when the user click the button and the data are send to Flask. This function create a marker on the map and set the data from function in Flask to marker popup. I use `form` in popup because I want to get the name form this popup. I want to submit this form from popup and get the name but when I do it `print("Name :",nazwa_event)` it return me None. I create a input with hidden tag in html and I set input value to the name from form  `$('input[id=nameOF]').val(nazwa.value);`. It is possible to do that or I can't submit form from `Ajax` ?

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="name_of_event"  class="form-control mb-2" name="name_event" placeholder="Nazwa wydarzenia">
                    <input name="nameOfEvent" type="hidden" value="" id="nameOF">
                    <br>
                    <button id="search-button_event" type='submit' name="event_form" class="btn btn-primary">Szukaj</button>
```

JS code:

```
$("#search-button_event").click(function () { // make ajax request on btn click
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mapaa", // url to the function
            data: {
                nameevent: $("#name_of_event").val(), // value of the form
            },
            success: function (response) {
                 
                 nazwa = (response['name']);
                 
                let marker_event = L.marker(array[0]).bindPopup()
                marker_event._popup.setContent(
                                                                '<form method="POST" action="/mapaa"'+
                                                                '<p>Nazwa: '+nazwa+'</p>'+
                                                                '<button type="submit" id="form-submit" name="form-submit"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Dołącz do wydarzenia</button>'+
                                                                '</form>')

                marker_event.addTo(mymap)

                polyline_event = L.polyline(array,{color: 'red'})
                marker_event.on('click',function(){
                    polyline_event.addTo(mymap)
                })
                marker_event.getPopup().on('remove', function() {
                    polyline_event.remove()
                })


                $('input[id=nameOF]').val(nazwa.value);
                mymap.setView(array[0],14)
            },
        });
    });
```

FLASK code:

```
@app.route('/mapaa',methods=['GET','POST'])
def mapa():
    user_id = current_user.get_id()
    slownik = {}

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.is_json:
            req = request.get_json()
            nazwa = req['name']
            data_pocz = req['data_start']
            data_kon = req['data_end']
            typ = req['type']
            dlugosc = req['len_route']
            coord = req['coordinates']
            event_database = Event(date_start=data_pocz, date_end=data_kon, type=typ, name=nazwa, len_route=dlugosc,admin=user_id, route=coord)
            db.session.add(event_database)
            db.session.commit()
            print('Dodano wydarzenie')




        if 'form-submit' in request.form:
            nazwa_event = request.form.get('nameOfEvent')
            print("Id ev:",nazwa_event)
            


        else:
            name_ev = request.form.get('nameevent')
            all_data = Event.query.filter_by(name=name_ev).all()
            for row in all_data:
                date_st_string = str(row.date_start)
                date_end_string = str(row.date_end)
                slownik = {'id':row.id,'date_st':date_st_string,'date_end':date_end_string,'type':row.type,'name':row.name,'len_route':row.len_route,'route':row.route}
            return jsonify(slownik)
    return render_template('mapaa.html', title='Mapa')
```

Comment: No, you can't submit a form with AJAX, you send the data your form contains instead.

Comment: So how can I do it in other way ? It is any way to do that?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings

Comment: maybe first check what you get in form - ie. `print( request.form )`  or `print( request.form.keys() )`

Comment: The return `request.form` me `ImmutableMultiDict([('form-submit', '')])` and `request.form.keys()` return me `<dict_keyiterator object at 0x0000019F99BA58B0>`

Comment: when I run some part of your code then I get `nameevent`, not `nameOfEvent` because you send `{nameevent: ...}`

Comment: if you want to send value from popup `form` then you should add some `<input>` inside this `form` - but you have nothing in this `form` - there is only `<button>`

Comment: it seems you create hiddent `<input ... id="nameOF">` in wrong `form` - you should put it in `form` inside popup (PL: wygląda na to, że tworzysz ukryty `<input ... id="nameOF">` w złej formie - powinnieneś ją umieścić w formie, która jest w popup)

Comment: I added `'<input name="nameOfEvent" type="hidden" value="" id="nameOF">'+` to popup and then ` $('input[id=nameOF]').val(nazwa.value);` to set value. I printed it in Flask using `request.form.get('nameOfEvent')` but it return me nothin I mean it is empty.

Comment: did you remove previous hidden `<input>` because now you may have two hidden inputs and it may set value in wrong place. Besides you could set this value  directly in `.setContent( ... )` without  `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but as for me you have hidden `<input>` in wrong place - it has to be inside `form` inside `popup`. And you can set value directly in HTML without using `jQuery`

```
marker_event._popup.setContent(
    '<form method="POST" action="/mapaa"' +
    
    '<input name="nameOfEvent" type="hidden" value="' + nazwa.value + '" id="nameOF">' + 
                
    '<p>Nazwa: ' + nazwa + '</p>' +
    '<button type="submit" id="form-submit" name="form-submit"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Dołącz do wydarzenia</button>' +
    '</form>'
)
```

I'm not sure if it should be `nazwa.value` or only `nazwa` like in `'<p>Nazwa: ' + nazwa + '</p>'`

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I changed that but now it return me `undefined` don't know why.

Comment: maybe it should be `nazwa` instead of `nazwa.value`